# Is there an NPM package to log a SQL database in node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I'm making an app that retrieves information from SQL databases and displays the info in node, but I'm a bit stuck in trying to find a way to print the entire table as a table instead of the loose individual data. Is there an npm package that might do this that you might recommend? If not, is there an obvious way to do this I'm not seeing?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used https://www.npmjs.com/package/table for this. See example for logging mysql output ( I'm using it in my simple mysql repl - https://github.com/sidorares/myki ):

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection(Object.assign({}, config, { rowsAsArray: true }));

const chalk = require('chalk');

function myEval(cmd, context, filename, callback) {
  connection.query(cmd, (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      if (!err.fatal) {
    console.log(chalk.red(err.message));
    return;
      } else {
        return callback(err);
      }
    }
    console.log(
      table([fields.map(f => chalk.bold(f.name))].concat(rows.map(r => r.map(c => util.inspect(c, { colors: true })))))
    );
    callback(null);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that looks like it could do the trick! I will try it now.